# Using BytesIO in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, github

I am getting a csv file from a url and I am trying to read it using pandas.read_csv with Python3, but I am getting a parserError for some reason. Here's the code:

```
csvurl = requests.get("https://github.com/cs109/2014_data/blob/master/countries.csv")
csvb = BytesIO(csvurl.content)
countries = pd.read_csv(csvb)
```

and I am getting the following error:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 114, saw 3

But line 114 is just the same as the other lines. Is the error related to me trying to read csv using Bytes object?

Comment: Did you have a look at `csvurl.content`? Try `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv` instaed.

Answer (score 3):

Use raw data url only:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv'
countries = pd.read_csv(url)
print (countries)

                              Country         Region
0                             Algeria         AFRICA
1                              Angola         AFRICA
2                               Benin         AFRICA
3                            Botswana         AFRICA
4                             Burkina         AFRICA
5                             Burundi         AFRICA
6                            Cameroon         AFRICA
7                          Cape Verde         AFRICA
8            Central African Republic         AFRICA
9                                Chad         AFRICA
```

Comment: Even using the url in this way is producing the same ParseError.

Comment: There is no problem with some firewall? Or some typo in url? Please check `pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv')`. It should works.