# pandas read_csv from BytesIO

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, bytesio

I have a BytesIO file-like object, containing a CSV.
I want to read it into a Pandas dataframe, without writing to disk in between.

## MWE

In my use case I downloaded the file straight into BytesIO. 
For this MWE I'll have a file on disk, read it into BytesIO, then read that into Pandas.
The disk step is just to make a MWE.

`file.csv`

```
a,b
1,2
3,4
```

Script:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
bio = BytesIO()
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
   bio.write(f.read())

# now we have a BytesIO with a CSV
df = pd.read_csv(bio)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas-io.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(bio)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1135, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1917, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Note that this sounds like a similar problem to the title of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392105/using-bytesio-in-pandas-read-csv), but the error messages are different, and that post has the X-Y problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The error says the file is empty.

That's because after writing to a `BytesIO` object, the file pointer is at the *end* of the file, ready to write more. So when Pandas tries to read it, it starts reading *after* the last byte that was written.

So you need to move the pointer back to the start, for Pandas to read.

```
bio.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(bio)
```